# Can't write anything in file with function syslog() after creating it with 777 permissions

Tags: c, linux, file-permissions

My program is creating a file with 777 permissions and trying to write logs in it with functions openlog() and syslog(), but it can't write anything in it until I reboot my computer(I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5).

My functions openlog() and syslog() are working correctly because after rebooting the computer program starts to write logs in the file.

Are there any other solutions to my problem besides rebooting the computer?

Comment: Why permissions 777? That's a wide gaping security risk. Never set executable bits on something that can be written by everyone and may ingest outside content.

Comment: @datenwolf At first I thought, that the problem is in permissions, that's why I changed it to 777, but thank you, I didn't know that it's a huge security risk, I will correct it.

Comment: If you use `syslog();`, you don't need to worry about creating files. And if you want to write to specific files, don't use `syslog()`.

Comment: @Cheatah Does it create the file by itself? And is there any other function that you would recommend? Thank you!

Comment: Just read the syslog documentation.